# Where to start to learn drawing online

Tags: drawing

I am almost new to drawing. I hadn't attempted to draw anything for over 20 years, then stumbled on a copy of "Drawing from the Right Side of the Brain" and decided to try. I got better fairly quickly and after completing the book I tried to continue improving through YouTube lessons.

Now my struggle is that I didn't find any online resources, either free or paid, that offers a comprehensive long term learning curve. I find neat tricks and techniques here and there, but often either realize halfway through that the author of the tutorial assumed knowledge I don't have, or try to cover the very basic skills I already saw 10 times elsewhere.

I didn't find lot of options for in person art classes in my region either.

So my question is, what would be the seriously good options to learn drawing online on the long run? I don't feel like randomly picking the next skill I think I guess to work is leading me anywhere.

I work with mainly with charcoal, and also a bit with soft pastel, but I'm more interested in learning drawing in general than in learning a medium in particular.

Comment: Look up tutorials. Find the ones that suit you. It depends on a lot of factors, including your current skills, your style, what you find incites you to keep working, etc. What we do here at Arts&Crafts is try to help people solve *specific* problems, not link them through to other places (unless as part of a solution, of course).

Comment: Drawing from the Right Side of the Brain should give you enough to get started. You do not need YouTube to tell you how to do it, you have what you need. The rest is practice. (Not that its a bad idea to get different inspiration, and YouTube can help with that.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in learning drawing without a specific medium, I recommend Udemy. It has a lot of great lessons, if you're willing to pay (~$15). My recommendation is https://www.udemy.com/course/the-ultimate-drawing-course-beginner-to-advanced/. Not only is the course long and comprehensive, but you can even ask the teacher questions about anything. He gives out assignments and reviews your submissions. You can see what other people submitted, too!

Note: I'm not sponsored in any way by Udemy or the course teacher. I took the course last year, and really enjoyed it.

Comment: Welcome to A&C! 
I was pondering suggesting Udemy as well, and it seems they have a lot of in-depth art classes to take.

Comment: Hi! That's very true. I learned a lot because I was able to contact the teacher and get responses quickly. I think that's what makes it better than YouTube.